# How can i create a bottom sheet with two divided list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: screenshot of the image]

how to create a bottom sheet with two divided lists I have tried the Cupertino picker but didn't do the job well. is there's a favorite way of doing this, please

Answer (score 0):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            top: Radius.circular(5),
          ),
        ),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: 250,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                 Expanded(
                   flex: 1,
                                    child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      // YOUR İTEMS
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        child: Text(  "İTEM 1"),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        child: Text(
                          "İTEM 2",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                 ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 4,
                                      child: Row(
                    children: [
                      // your picker 
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                      child: CupertinoPicker()),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: CupertinoPicker())
                    ],
                    ),
                  )

              ],
            ));});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ModalBottomsheet Instead

```
showModalBottomSheet(
       context: context,
       builder: (context) {
               return Column(
                 children: [
                     Expanded(child : Container(height : 20,color : Colors.red)), //change as require
                     Expanded(child : Container(height : 40,color : Colors.yellow)), //change as require
                        ]
                       )
                       }
```